# Numbers in hindi words

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I can change the format of the number using "format cells" dialog box

```
#,##0.00
```

This will display the number like this...

> ```
> 789.00
> ```

I can also change numbers to text using this...

```
[NatNum12 cardinal][$ $]
```

It will display the same number in words like:

> ```
> seven hundred eighty-nine $
> ```

I can change the display to devnagari numbers using the custom format:

```
[NatNum1][$-439]#,##0.00
```

It will display the same number in devnagari:

> ```
> ७८९.००
> ```

But I am not able to convert that hindi number to hindi text.
The expected output is something like this...

> सात सौ नवासी

Comment: Yes, this is an unfortunate mistake. Perhaps it is worth [**informing the developers**](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/enter_bug.cgi) about it.

Please check - maybe using the [**Numbertext extension**](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/numbertext-1) will be better than formatting?

Comment: Tried. https://github.com/Numbertext/libnumbertext/issues/86#issuecomment-857541333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hindi is not currently supported by libnumbertext, perhaps because Indo-Aryan language numbers are notoriously irregular. Supported languages are at https://numbertext.github.io/#testimonials, according to the LO 6.1 [release notes](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/6.1#New_.E2.80.9Cspell_out.E2.80.9D_NatNum_modifier).

Marathi *does* work, so perhaps other Indo-Aryan languages will be added in future releases. For example, changing the cell format locale to `Marathi` with code `[NatNum12 cardinal] 0` shows `सातशे एकोणनव्वद`. In contrast,  when Hindi is selected, the numerals remain as `789` only.